# How to respond to an XSS attack

Tags: security, web, xss

I've seen a lot of info on OWASP and around the web that talk about how to avoid/prevent XSS attacks. However, I have yet to find anything that mentions how to respond when an XSS attack has been detected.

What HTTP Status Code should be returned (i.e 400, 403...)?
Should you provide an error message on the screen or on console.log?
Redirect them to another page?

Comment: I think you should read a bit more on the subject :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send an HTTP 400 (Bad Request) response code, and a minimal error message, sufficient that tech support could help a legitimate user, but not give info to an attacker.

Log the request as well.

A legit user might enter some info they shouldn't so you shouldn't take overly harsh measures.

A real world example is Hibernate Validator's @SafeHtml validation, which will cause a 400 status code if the input is possible XSS.